# Правильно ли построено предложение? С винительным и именительным падежами

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, падежи

***Квас чай не испортит.***

Вот, собственно, предложение.

Это предложение можно понимать в двух смыслах:

1. Квас не испортится от чая.
   Ну и, следовательно, наоборот:
2. Чай не испортится от кваса.

Если рассматривать именительный падеж, а также винительный,
получается:

(именительный: Кто? Что?) *Квас* (винительный: Кого? Что?) *чай не испортит.*

(винительный: Кого? Что?) *Квас* (именительный: Кто? Что?) *чай не испортит.*

Правильны ли эти высказывания?

Comment: Александр, тут стоял вопрос именно в том что правильно ли было составлено то предложение и каким правилом пользоваться что бы составить его правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Правильно ли построено предложение?** Если это поговорка, то есть единственная фраза в данном тексте на эту тему, то построение **некорректное**. Почему?

(1) В поговорке смысл такой, что сходные материи не конфликтуют; с другой стороны, прочтение предложения задается **порядком слов** (мы делим фразу на две равновесные части, а естественное ударение делаем в конце каждой): Квас чАй // не испОртит.

(2) Другое замечание **к стилистике**: предложение должно читаться и пониматься **однозначно,** а здесь возможны варианты (поэтому это его недостаток). Лучше выразиться с большей определенностью: *Квас чаем не испортишь. Чай квасом не испортишь.*

2. **Реальный текст** — другое дело, там смысл и порядок слов определяется контекстом (тема — рема, о чем говорим — что говорим, и все такое).
3. Таким образом, не надо забывать, что все **в мире относительно**, однозначности там не сыщешь, а все правильное корректно только **в определенных пределах**. Как скажут математики, надо задать **область определения**. Все-таки математический язык удобен для формулировки суждений и доказательств.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы, подобные конструкции воспринимаются двусмысленно. Часто такое бывает с иностранными именами: "Лиз оберегала Мари": кто кого оберегал?
Поэтому в тексте лучше такие конструкции переформулировать: **квас чаем не испортишь** или **чай квасом не испортишь** — в зависимости от авторской мысли. **Мари была оберегаема Лиз** (несмотря на то, что страдательный залог звучит по-канцелярски).

Comment: Благодарю, но еще раз повторюсь, вопрос состоял в то что можно ли вообще так сказать. Ситуация в том что возник спор. Но душа прям отвергает это выражение, но я же не могу это сказать собеседнику в лоб. Вот и думаю как я должен был понять собеседника. Хоть и был контекст.

Comment: @Кирилл контекст может исправить ситуацию, если из него явно следует, какой напиток основной. К примеру: "Я люблю попивать квас, разбавленный чаем. Чай квас не испортит!" — тут ясно, что  чай (и. п) не испортит квас (в. п.), потому что чай добавлялся в квас и, следовательно, квас как бы основной, первичный напиток. *Пока перелом срастался, Мари была беспомощна. Всё это время Лиз оберегала Мари*.